# How to send multiple array in JSON in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have a 3 `<tr></tr>` in my table. user can edit them and on the save button I send the data to the server.

first is main and other all is child of the main. When someone click on new button a new child is created.

now I am thinking to maintain the information like this

```
  var minf = {};
    minf.main = $("#tr" + curSplidId).find('input,select').serialize();



 res.each(function(n) {
            var i = $(this).find('input,select').serialize();
            minf[n] = i;
        });
```

All I am trying to do is getting main object and array of childs in JsonResult, I have tried to use Dictionary for JSON.stringify values.

None of these works.

Someone please help me to get it done. Through my testing I found in a case it's sending me querystring in my minf object (I does Stringify) but I am not sure how to handle it on JSONResult as some kind of dictionary stuff where I can read it through the keys.

Comment: Show your code of the function, which is passing array to server

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a 3 tr. the best approach is to use a loop on all the tr and create a object same to the DTO that is using in action and make a list of it.

```
        var MainList=[];
        $('tr').each(function(){

         var MainDTO={};
         MainDTO.Column1=$(this).find('td').html();
         MainDTO.Column2=$(this).find('td').html();
         MainList.add(MainDTO)

        });
```

and pass this MainList directly to action. no serialise required

Comment: This HTML is too large and I only want to send the input value from select and input.

Comment: so you can only find that input value : for example
MainDTO.Column1 = $(this).find('td input').val();
MainDTO.Column1 = $(this).find('td Select option:selected').val();

Comment: I write exact the same code as yours 2 hours ago, but with input (check my code) the problem is not with sending but a way that server can understand. check my answer.

Comment: so you need to place a list of that object on server side code as well

Answer (score 0):

I think for converting data to json and read that json on server. I make the whole process hard for JS and server to handle.

I change the strategy to serialize all the element and send it to server. it's work fine.

now if I need to read id then I can parse the id which is 3 and come in comma based values.